# Ripple effect does work for long press in List tile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I wrapped List tile widget with gesture widget because I want to execute some code on onLongPressStart and onLongPressEnd Call back. But due to this the ripple effect does not work in case of longpress. It work file for simple tap. When I remove these call back from gesture widget the ripple effect works. How can I fix this issue?

Here is example of what I am doing:

```
GestureDetector(

                    onLongPressStart: (value){
                      //do something
                    },
                    onLongPressEnd: (value){
                      //do something
                    },
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text("Title"),
                      onTap: (){
                        // do something
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: so you want to start a ripple effect on long press or something else?

Comment: No, actually ripple effect display like it is a simple tab after that  it is like widget is not pressed. I want to show that the tile is still press (its background color should change)

Comment: sorry i have no idea what you really want to achieve

Comment: What I want is " as long as the widget is pressed its background color should remain changed. For example: If tile is white after widget is pressed it should display grey. After long press ends it color should change to white"

Comment: so the ripple starts if you press your finger and disappears when you release your finger? so why we talk about **long press** at all? or you mean the ripple starts on long press?

Comment: Ripple starts when I press my finger but stops simultaneously while my finger is still pressed(long press case). I want that when I release my finger only than ripple stops.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223080/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InkRipple did the trick for me. Here is the code

```
class PressRipple extends StatefulWidget {
    final Widget child;
    final VoidCallback onPress;

    PressRipple({
        Key key,
        this.child,
        @required this.onPress,
    }) : assert(onPress != null), super(key: key);

    @override
    _PressRippleState createState() => _PressRippleState();
}

class _PressRippleState extends State<PressRipple> {
    InteractiveInkFeature _inkFeature;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTapDown: (d) {
        _inkFeature = InkRipple(
            position: d.localPosition,
        color: Colors.green,
        controller: Material.of(context),
        referenceBox: context.findRenderObject(),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        containedInkWell: true,
        );
        widget.onPress();
    },
        onTapUp: (d) {
        _inkFeature.dispose();
    },
        child: widget.child,
        );
    }
}
```

And Then use it like this

```
SizedBox(
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: PressRipple(
          onPress: () {
            print('on press callback');
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Thanks @pskink for help

Comment: Does this work as expected always? When I tried running this code, on multiple taps the whole container becomes green and stays stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this structure. Long press triggers "splash color" and gives color. If you keep the opacity of the color in the "container" field low, the "splash color" will not be lost.

```
InkWell(
    splashColor: Colors.blue,
    onTap: () {
        print('Clicked');
    },
    child: Container(
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
        child: ListTile(
            title: Text('Text'),
        ),
    ),
)
```